# Automatic distribution of TLS certificate to clients on renewal of server certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate

In my application we have a Server offering some REST APIs. There are clients connected to it consuming the APIs.

To secure this we uses TLSv1.2. It works like

1. Server generates a self-signed certificate with less validity.
2. Server certificate is copied to all clients manually.
3. Clients does only server validation.

This has been working fine since we run in controlled environment (server not exposed to outside world) and we have very less clients. Now the number of clients are increasing and manually copying the certificate every time on expiry is a difficult task. Is there any standard approach to distribute TLS certificates to clients automatically ?.

I understand there could be other ways to solve this like.

1. Start using a root CA with higher validity. Let root CA sign the server certificate. We distribute root CA to client once. Here too we may have to re-distribute the root CA certificate if it expires.
2. A full fledged certificate management framework via Certificate Management Protocol implementation.

I was trying to check if there is a standard approach for certificate distribution  to solve the problem with existing implementation.

Could someone please share your expertise on this topic ?

Thanks
JK

Comment: Use a CA-signed certificate. Solves the whole problem at a stroke.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using the tag. `distribution` is not what you think.

Comment: Sorry for using wrong tag.Regarding using CA signed certificate, even in that case too it comes with a validity (more time frame than self signed though) . From that aspect isn't the problem just postponed ?. Please correct me if I over looked anything